# Eclipse , Gradle , Lombok : lombog config not read while connected to RTC

Tags: eclipse, gradle, lombok, rtc, ibm-jazz

I have simple gradle project in Eclipse ( neon ) that uses Lombok. Lombok is installed properly in Eclipse (version 1.16.16). The project works fine and reflects the contents from configuration file ( lombok.config) as long as the project is not connected to Rational Team Concert. Lombok still works while connected to RTC , but config file will not be read . I need Lombok to reflect config file content while still connected to RTC. If I disconnect from RTC, then it starts working fine again. Is it known issue or am I missing any configuration?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that lombok will search the files on disk for the configuration file, starting at the directory the java file is located in, and then bubble up to the root of the file system, or a lombok.config file is found with the line `config.stopBubbling = true`.

From the past, I remember that Rational (or actually Jazz) stores project files in different directories.

A possible solution is to put `lombok.config` in your `src` directory instead of your project root.

Comment: That did not work either. I did try putting lombok.config in `src` as well as `resources` when it  did not work from root. Thanks for your input .